# What does this announcer say after the words 改变？

Tags: pronunciation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0D-ot2tso8

This is that somewhat controversial commercial for laundry soap.  It's at about the :40 second mark.  Is he saying 帅哥？

Thank you,
Rachel

Comment: No, 帅哥 does not exist

Comment: Note that Youtube is blocked in China

Comment: “改变，只需一颗俏比洗衣溶珠。俏比全国招商热线：xxx-xxx-xxxx。” 

"To change, all it takes is one QiaoBi detergent soap. To join QiaoBi franchise call nation-wide hotline xxx-xxx-xxxx."

Comment: one bead of Qiaobi laundry detergent?

Comment: cf.中国洗衣粉广告因涉嫌种族歧视而引发公愤  http://www.rfa.org/mandarin/yataibaodao/renquanfazhi/nu-05272016113618.html

Comment: 中国外交部回应歧视广告 引发更强烈反弹 http://www.rfa.org/mandarin/yataibaodao/renquanfazhi/xl2-05312016140850.html

Answer (score 2):

No. He's not saying the word "帅哥". What he says is "改变，只需一颗俏比洗衣溶珠" as  @NS.X. comments.